# Why does converting a .ts stream to .mp4 result in a longer duration

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-conversion, transport-stream

Using ffmpeg to convert a .ts file to .mp4 format sometimes results in the converted video's duration being longer than its original.

**What would be causing this to happen?**

I've only found answers online that point towards timestamps and different primary and sub channels being one of the reasons.

I use the following `ffmpeg` command to convert the files:

```
ffmpeg -i fileName.ts -map 0 -c copy outputName.mp4
```

Comment: There is not enough information on this question to be able to answer it without guessing.  Please read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question and come back to [edit] it and improve it.  Good questions tend to solicit quicker, better responses from the community.

Comment: @blurfus I'm not sure what other information I can provide. Could you please elaborate on what I could add or what other information is needed?

Comment: I am assuming you already read the link in my comment above.  If not, that's a good point of reference. For starters, we have incomplete info: what OS are we using? what version of the software?  A bit of clarification about resulting in a longer duration (do you mean a bigger file? or a longer video?) - assuming is a longer video, what's the difference in length? (a couple or a dozen seconds? milliseconds?) - streams do take time to 'start streaming' (buffering) could that be an issue?  does it happen all the time? only some times?

Comment: Also, come to think about it more, perhaps this question is better suited for https://superuser.com as it does not seem to be a programming question but a software use issue

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.